# Ag grid display in grouping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Attached my plunker link [https://plnkr.co/edit/lnF09XtK3eDo1a5v]

It works, however I wanted to remove line separator from group columns and keep group column data in center.

I tried with to  update CSS as shown in plunker but still not coming in center

`display:none, center`

Current grid -
[[image]] 'image'

Comment: plunker link [https://plnkr.co/edit/lnF09XtK3eDo1a5v]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try overwrite this Ag-Grid Css rules:

```
.ag-row {
    border: transparent!important;
}
```

With that, you take the borders of the lines, and to add bottom borders for each cell, you could use the cellStyle function to your gridOptions:

```
cellStyle : params => (params.colDef.headerName === 'Country' || params.colDef.headerName === 'Year') && !params.value
? { borderBottom: 'solid transparent' }
: { border-bottom: '1px solid #dde2eb' }
```

Comment: Thanks this works (I have updated as per suggestion), however do we have option to put a border between different group values..in this example country is group and let says UnitedStates rows are completed , can we get bottom border to depict end of group value